# How can I fetch data like text, image and video on my index page from MySql Database using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

i am making a php project social media like facebook. in timeline page a i want to show ther user post like text, image or video or all these. i am confuse to make a code. 
my uploading code is this

```
if(isset($text)){
    $flagt=1;
}
if(isset($name)){
    $flagi=1;
}
if(isset($video)){
    $flagv=1;
}
if($flagt==0 && $flagi==0 && $flagv==0) {
    echo "nothing to upload";
}
else{
    $sql="insert into post(u_id,p_text,p_image,p_video)values('{$_SESSION['id']}',";
    $val=0;
    if ($flagt==1) {
        $val="'$text'";
    }

         if ($flagi==1 && $flagt==1) {
            $val.=",'$name'";
            upload('image','../user_uploads');

        }

        if ($flagt==1 && $flagi==1 && $flagv==1) {

            $val.=",'$video'";
            upload('image','../user_uploads');
            upload('video','../video');
            if ($flagt==1 && $flagi ==0 && $flagv==1) {

                $val.=",'$video'";
                upload('video','../video');
                if ($flagt==0 && $flagi ==1 && $flagv==1) {

                    $val.=",'$video'";
                    upload('image','../user_uploads');
                    upload('video','../video');

                }
            }
        }


    $sql.=$val.")";

}
```

any one can help me?
i want to show this data at my timeline page

Comment: You just need to fetch the data from database which you want to display. If you don't know how to fetch data from database using PHP then you can find tons of tutorials online.

Comment: You should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that.

Comment: `values('{$_SESSION['id']}',` highly vulnerable to SQL injection, parentheses not closed

Comment: Also, you're asking about fetching data while showing us some code for inserting data? You really need to do some research, read the manual/some tutorials and try to solve the issue yourself before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: You can use blob fields or store files separately and store only the path in DB.

Answer (score 0):

using php pdo fetch data from database.

```
  $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT u_id,p_text,p_image,p_video FROM post ORDER BY count DESC');
  $stmt->execute();
  $posts = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

now use $posts to show data in timeline page.

```
  <?php if (isset($posts)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <!-- posts -->
    <div class="clearfix">
        <p><?php echo $post['p_text']; ?></p>
        <?php if (isset($post['p_image'])): ?>
         <img src='<?php echo $post['p_image']; ?>'>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if (isset($post['p_video'])): ?>
         <img src='<?php echo $post['p_video']; ?>'>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```